# Position absolute removes hyperlink from image.

Tags: php, html, css, absolute

I've got the following code:

```
<div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 48px; margin-left: 261px;">
    <a href="http://www.somepage.com" target="_blank">
        <?php $image_url='http://www.somepage.com/image.jpg'; ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $image_url;?>">
    </a>
</div>
```

The image displays and positions correctly and the hyperlink works fine without the "position: absolute" but when it's included as above the link does not work.

I'm by no means a PHP programmer or even a programmer for that matter. So I'm probably missing something obvious here? any help would extremely appreciated.

Comment: Please post a link to a JSFiddle or your working page.

Comment: jsfiddle cant interpret php

Comment: Do you realize that your anchor's href is "http://www.http://www.somepage.com"?  That's not a valid link because of the double http://

Comment: What's the html generated by the php page?

Comment: @Luis the html is in my answer, if we can get more code/info, ill edit it to reflect any findings

Comment: It looks like it is working on my end (trying it within a php site) - do you have a link you could share, by chance?

Comment: Add `z-index:100` to style

Answer (score 0):

[Worken](http://jsfiddle.net/cEVpN/) ---> It's working fine enough tried it on localhost also, there something else thats causing your problem

code:

```
<div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 48px; margin-left: 261px;">
    <a href="http://www.somepage.com" target="_blank">
        <img style = "border:1px solid black;" src="http://www.somepage.com/image.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

as a side note:i find it humorous that it links to an actual page

**EDIT:**

Glad to see you have figured it out a tad, heres another solution i just thought of:

```
#logo{
    background-image:url(http://www.somepage.com/image.jpg);
    height:400px;
    width:40px;
}

<div style="position: absolute; margin-top: 48px; margin-left: 261px;">
    <a href="http://www.somepage.com" target="_blank" id = "logo">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, the actual page is here: http://rezzonatormusic.com/ so the small red log (PRS in red) is in the right place, if I remove the "position: absolute"  style it breaks the other layout. But the hyperlink on the image then works, whereas now it does not.

Comment: Here's a JSFidle http://jsfiddle.net/MztDQ/ and it works there, so there's something causing a bug, I'm using this on the header of a Wordpress site. would z-index (which I've tried) or something else work? I've also played with overflow to no luck.

Comment: Hi @John_Doe, thanks for taking a look if by the link you mean rezzonatormusic above, it's probably server overload from Godaddy as I couldn't get through around the time of your reply either. I've found an almost workable solution, though not very elegant. I'm using the original code that actually works on all pages of the site including the hyperlink, with the exception of the homepage. I then have a similar duplication of the code, that shows on the homepage but the link does not work, just a couple of divs above the first one.

Comment: @Pedro added another posible solution.

Comment: Thanks again John, I'm going to stick with what I've got there for now  as it's taken far more time than I wanted to. I must make a point of turning up her more often and answer a few questions if I can find any I'm able to answer.